# Perform insert,search and delete queries on an array in less than O(n) time and using O(1) auxiliary space

Tags: arrays, data-structures, time-complexity

I am given an array of numbers and allowed to preprocess them .
There are 3 types of queries :

Insert(x) which inserts an element "x" into the array.
Delete(x) which deletes an element "x" from the array (assume x is present in the array)
Find(x) which returns if "x" is present in the array .

I am allowed to use only constant auxillary space .

Is there a way to answer these queries in less than *O(n)* time . If not, can this be proved ? Even a small improvement in query time will be useful .

Comment: Are you familiar with binary search trees?

Comment: @templatetypedef - Yes, but I can't see how it can be built using constant auxillary space . I know that heaps can be built only using array and without pointers , but I am not familar with a similar technique to build a balanced binary search tree in *O(1)* space .

Comment: Oh, you're right. You can't even build a BST with O(1) auxiliary space. My mistake.

Comment: I don't have the answer, but [this link](http://bigocheatsheet.com) can be relevant

Comment: Why not hash table ? It has worst case of O(n) for insert, delete and find.

Comment: @Biswanath I want a solution which uses only constant auxiliary space . A Hash table will take O(maximum_value_in_array) . And AFAIK , insert,search and delete should take *O(1)* time rather than *O(n)* . Please correct me if I am wrong .

Comment: I was mentioning worst case(using separate chaining for buckets) not amortised.For amortised you are right. Sorry, but I don't understand, how "maximum value in the array" have anything to say about the hash table size.

Comment: Also I think constant auxiliary space should take out hash table. I can't think of any but a array and in place sorting for pre processing for O(n) insert, delete and O(logn) for search.

Comment: @Biswanath - You are correct . I just read about hash tables . I was imagining a boolean array from 0 to max_value_of_array which would have true for every element present in the array and false otherwise.

The currently posted answer is the best that I can see . I am unable to see any way to improve the worst case time of *O(n)* .

Comment: Suppose we have an array of N elements, and we want to insert a new element. We don't have the space to do that! How do we get more? Do we have to allocate a buffer of size N+1 and copy everything over? In that case, we can't get below O(N) for inserts. Can we allocate a buffer of size 2N? In that case, we can get better amortized insert performance, but we're using O(N) extra space. Do we realloc the array to size N+1 and hope it always succeeds in place? That may not be realistic. And what if the memory allocator always allocates in power-of-2-sized chunks? We might use O(N) extra space...

Comment: without even realizing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an implementation that still has O(n) runtime for insert and delete, but which gets lookups running in time O(log n).

Have as your data structure a dynamically-allocated, sorted array with no slack space. To perform a lookup, just use binary search in time O(log n).

To do an insertion, allocate a new array of n+1 elements. Copy over the existing elements, inserting the new element in its correct sorted position. This takes time O(n). Deletion could be implemented similarly.

You could speed things up a bit by picking some fixed constant k, then overallocating the array by k elements every time you need to grow. This means that only once in k elements do you need to actually copy the array, so while the worst-case runtime will still be O(n), the amortized cost of an insertion or deletion becomes O(n / k). For constant k this is asymptotically the same as before, but in practical terms this could make a huge difference.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

Yes we can do in O(1) in array .
insert(x) means insertion in last it'll default O(1), delete(x) means delete with index and put last index to deleted index so again it's O(1), for search internally use hash map which gives you O(1) .

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this answer. What do you mean by "delete with index?" Also, how can you use a hash table with only O(1) auxiliary storage space?